# dompdf does wrong calculation for line breaks breaking words

Tags: php, dompdf

I'm using dompdf 0.5.2 and having the problem that when there is an accent on a line, the first character from the next line is moved into it, like:

```
This is a first line with áccent. T
his is a second line.
```

Notice the T at the end of the first line, it belongs to the second. It happens both with a default and a custom loaded font. Also tried with UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 encodings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked, taken from [here](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Stars%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=146), is adding the following line of code to the dompdf file `include/text_frame_reflower.cls.php` after line 246:

```
$split = mb_strlen(mb_substr($this->_frame->get_text(), 0, $split), 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution that worked for me is using the [wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) PHP function on your text/string .

Answer (score 2):

If someone have the same issue with the 0.7.0-beta version, the solution is adding the following line to the file src/Dompdf/FrameReflower/Text.php on line 272 (just before `if ($split == 0) {`):

```
$split = mb_strlen(mb_substr($this->_frame->get_text(), 0, $split), 'UTF-8');
```